# How to change app-id but keep the same resource-id?

Tags: android

In an Android project, the resource ids are fully identified by the application id. For example, if my appid is com.mycompany.myapp, the resource id would be com.mycompany.myapp.R.blah.

In my case, I need to create two versions of the app - beta version and release version. Both the versions may be installed on the same device. This can happen only if the appids are not the same. My strategy is, during the nightly build, I will programmatically modify the manifest file and change the appid to com.mycompany.myappbeta. However, if I do this, I would need to touch a number of source files that are using the resource ids.

I am wondering if there is some token in the manifest file where I can explicitly say how the resource ids be qualified? Regards.

**Edit**

It turns out app id and package id are indeed two different concepts. I wanted to change the app-id but not the package-id. However, it seems this is not possible under Eclipse. As other posts have pointed out, Gradle build can handle changing the app-id but retaining the package id. I am moving over to Android Studio now.

Comment: ids are automatically generated and stored in **R.java**. You shouldn't be concerned about that. And should never touch that file. Nor use id values **explicitly**. Just use the `findViewById()` and `getId()` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the resource ids are fully identified by the application id

Technically, they are identified by the package name, from the `package` attribute in the root manifest.

> My strategy is, during the nightly build, I will programmatically modify the manifest file and change the appid to com.mycompany.myappbeta. However, if I do this, I would need to touch a number of source files that are using the resource ids.

Which is why your nightly build should be using Gradle and the Gradle for Android plugin. Then, you skip all of what you described, and instead use build types. Two build types (`debug` and `release`) are pre-defined, and if you want to invent another one (e.g., `beta`), you can. Then, in the build type configuration in your `build.gradle` file, you use `applicationIdSuffix` to give non-`release` builds a distinct suffix. That will be added to the application ID for the purposes of unique installations, but your package name is unaffected, so your resources are unaffected.

For example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('HelloConfig.keystore')
            keyAlias 'HelloConfig'
            storePassword 'laser.yams.heady.testy'
            keyPassword 'fw.stabs.steady.wool'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
          applicationIdSuffix ".d"
        }

        release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        beta.initWith(buildTypes.release)

        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

Here I:

- Give the `debug` build type an application ID suffix of `.d`
- Leave the `release` build type along from the standpoint of an application ID suffix
- Create a new `beta` build type, cloned from the `release` build type, where I give it a `.beta` application ID suffix and mark it as debuggable

Comment: Thank you. I have marked this as the right answer. Please look at my edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I do this, I would need to touch a number of source files that are using the resource ids.

No, you will not. You just need to change package id in your Manifest file only, ensuring however all services and activities listed in manifest file are using **full** class path, i.e.:

```
android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity"
```

not just shortened notation:

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

as this make your app not working when package Id will not match with your code packages.

Comment: Can you explain the "not just shortened notation" part? Doesn't that just automatically assume the full length value ?

Comment: if your app packageid matches name of your "root" java package name, then both references would be equal, but if not, then you will end up with framework looking for your `.MainActivity` in `<packageId>.MainActivity` package. And there's no such, so you will end up crashing.